# my object is not getting added in crudcrud api

Tags: javascript, api, rest, axios

So I am trying to get value through get element ID and through axios I am trying to do post request, but it's not getting added and in my network tab its status is showing cancelled

and when I check my crudcrud API dashboard it shows nothing I have tried every possible way i don't know what's wrong with code and I have also checked my API through postman and browser it's working fine there is no problem with API

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/1.4.0/axios.min.js"></script>

    <script>
       
        //to add element to screen
    function bar() {
        

        console.log('started');

        const name1 = document.getElementById('name').value;
        const email1 = document.getElementById('email').value;
        const phone = document.getElementById('phone_no').value;

        
        console.log(name1,email1,phone)
        myobj = {
            name1,
            email1,
            phone
        };
        console.log(myobj);

            //localStorage.setItem(pp, JSON.stringify(myobj));
        axios.post('https://crudcrud.com/api/49a5697aa0584c5c9963fa21d697dd25',myobj
                
            
            ).then(res=>{
                console.log(res.data)
                let newdiv = document.createElement('div');
            let newli = document.createElement('li');
            let delete_btn=document.createElement('button')

            let edit_btn=document.createElement('button')
            edit_btn.type='submit'
            edit_btn.textContent='edit'
            edit_btn.onclick=ll;
            delete_btn.onclick=ss;
            delete_btn.type='submit'
            delete_btn.textContent='delete';
            newli.textContent = `name is ${myobj.name} and email is ${myobj.email} and phone is ${myobj.phone}`;
            newli.appendChild(delete_btn)
            newli.appendChild(edit_btn)
            newdiv.appendChild(newli);
            

            document.body.appendChild(newdiv);
             })
            .catch((err)=>{console.log(err)})
            console.log('its done')

            
  
}

function ss(e)//to delete file
{   
    
    e.preventDefault()
    let item=e.target.parentElement
    let newobj = item.cloneNode(true); // clone the li element to remove the delete button
    newobj.removeChild(newobj.lastChild)
    let dl=JSON.parse(newobj.textContent)
    console.log(dl);
    item.remove()
    localStorage.removeItem(dl.email)
}

function ll(e)//to update element
{
    e.preventDefault()
    let item=e.target.parentElement
    let newobj = item.cloneNode(true); // clone the li element to remove the delete button
    newobj.removeChild(newobj.lastChild)
    newobj.removeChild(newobj.lastChild)
    let dl=JSON.parse(newobj.textContent)
    console.log(dl);

    const lname=document.getElementById('name')
    const lemail=document.getElementById('email')
    const lphone=document.getElementById('phone_no')

    lname.value=dl.name
    lemail.value=dl.email
    lphone.value=dl.phone
    item.remove()
    localStorage.removeItem(dl.email)
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const form = document.querySelector('form');
  form.addEventListener('submit', bar);
  
});

            
            
        
        
        
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="">
        <label for="name"> name</label>
        <input type="text" id="name">
        <label for="email">email</label>
        <input type="text" id="email">
        <label for="phone_no">phone number</label>
        <input type="text" id="phone_no">

        <button type="submit" >submit</button>

    </form>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you debug in the browser, is the AJAX request being canceled because the page is reloading from submitting the form?

Comment: the script tag must be before the ending tag of body not at the head!

Comment: thanks it got solved i needed to add e.preventdefault on form onsubmit func